# MySQL PHP use query result more that once in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an query that shows data from db. I use while loop to display data. Problem is that I can call (echo) result only once.

Here is my code:

```
$ime_ = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE '" . ($_COOKIE['username']) . "' = user_username";
$ime_result = $mysqli->query($ime_);
```

and later in my html I use this result as:

```
<?php                                   
    if ($ime_result->num_rows > 0) 
        while($row = $ime_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<h2>" . $row["Ime"] . "</h2>";
        }
?>
```

This work ok, but I want to use this result to display many times in my html. And when copy while loop again later in html no result is given.

Comment: Instead of echoing the results in a loop, add the results to an array in the loop.  Then you can loop over that array as many times as you like.

Comment: Side note: Are you sure you want to use this type of design? In using a cookie name as a column? What you posted contains errors, btw.

Comment: I am new at this, basicly i need to extract name of user (not login name) from cookie. I created cookie falowing tutorian online and i do not know how to addname of user into the cookie.

Comment: try session storage instead of cookies https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the string with data from `while()` into a variable, than apply `echo` to that variable as many times as you like..

```
$re_out ='';
if($ime_result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $ime_result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $re_out .="<h2>". $row["Ime"] ."</h2>";
  }
}

echo $re_out;
//etc..
echo $re_out;
```

Comment: This work but i got error when i try to echo it.

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'Ime'`

Comment: Oh, sorry i type wrong. I use `echo $re_out[ime];` insead `echo $re_out;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                                   
    if ($ime_result->num_rows > 0)   
       $ime_result->data_seek(0); // seek to row no. 1
        while($row = $ime_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<h2>" . $row["Ime"] . "</h2>";
        }
?>
```

Haven't run script. Try if it works.